# ExactTarget PHP Fuel Update QueryDefinition

Tags: marketing-cloud, php, fuel

I am trying to create some sugar methods for Query's since for some reason they are missing form the Fuel SDK.

I have create, retrieve, execute & delete but I cannot figure out how to do the update.

can someone post a sample of how to update an existing query please.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of updating an existing QueryDefinition...
http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/updating_a_query_activity

Comment: Andrew, please copy and paste code sample here as opposed to the link only answer. Links are known to change.